# C++ Casting from reference

Tags: c++, casting

I'm attempting to re-create the `any` that is found in `Boost::any` and I have built the three classes, however, whenever I come to `reinterpret_cast` for the value that is given, the output is completely different and just throws out garbage. Here is my code below:

```
namespace Types {

class PlaceMaker {

    public:
        PlaceMaker() { };
        virtual ~PlaceMaker()
        {
        }

        virtual PlaceMaker * clone()  
        { 
            return 0; 
        }

        virtual const std::type_info & type() const = 0;
    protected:
};

template<typename T>
class holder : public PlaceMaker {

    public:
        holder(const T & value) 
        : held(value)
        {

        }

        virtual const std::type_info & type() const
        {
            return typeid(T);
        }

        virtual PlaceMaker * clone() const
        {
            return new holder(held);
        }

        T retrunHeld() const {
            return held;
        }
    public:
        T held;

        //holder &operator=(const holder &) const = 0;

        holder & operator=(const holder &) { }
};

class Any : PlaceMaker {

    public:
        Any() : maker(0) { };

        template<typename ValueType>
        Any(const ValueType & value)
           : maker(new holder<ValueType>(value))
        {

        }

        Any(const Any & other)
           : maker(other.maker ? other.maker->clone() : 0)
        {

        }

        Any& swap(Any &rhs) {
            std::swap(maker, rhs.maker);
            return *this;
        }

        template<typename ValueType>
        Any & operator=(const ValueType & rhs)
        {
            Any(rhs).swap(*this);
            return *this;
        }

        Any & operator=(Any rhs)
        {
            rhs.swap(*this);
            return *this;
        }

        bool empty() const
        {
            return !maker;
        }

        const std::type_info & type() const
        {
            return maker ? maker->type() : typeid(void);
        }

        template<typename T>
        T& cast() {
          T* r = reinterpret_cast<T*>(maker);
          return *r;
        }
    public:

        PlaceMaker * maker;
};
```

In main I have the following:

```
int main() {

    Types::Any a = 10;
    std::cout << a.cast<int>();
}

// output: 96458224
```

Could anyone tell me as to where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're casting a Holder* to a T*. Given that Holder has virtual functions in it, that means you're gonna be looking at the vtable, not the T itself.

Comment: Thank's for your reply, do you have any suggestions to how I could resolve the issue? I'm guessing I need to somehow get the value of `held` but I don't see a way to obtain it?

Comment: Well, first of all, it doesn't really make sense for both Any and holder to subclass PlaceMaker. But in any case, you can static_cast 'maker' to a holder of the appropriate type, then return its 'held'. (reinterpret_cast doesn't really have a role to play here.)

Comment: Thanks! But if I use `static_cast` so.. `T r = static_cast<T>(&maker); return *r;` I get the following error: `invalid static_cast from type 'Types::PlaceMaker**' to type 'int'` argh :(

Comment: Why would you use the reference operator on 'maker'? It's already a pointer. Also, again, what you need to cast it to is 'holder<T>*', because that's _what it is_.

Comment: Please give me an example? If I therefore cast.. `T r = static_cast<T>(holder<T>);` that cannot be right? Surly since the constructor in `holder` requires the value and at `cast` i do not pass in a value?

Comment: FFS, `return static_cast<holder<T>*>(maker)->held;`. But I think you might want to do a quick review of how the referencing and dereferencing operators work, and maybe take on a slightly more straightforward project. Safely discarding type-safety is a difficult proposition, and one that requires some fairly advanced C++ to do properly.